# How to avoid the wildcard in the return type

Tags: java, unbounded-wildcard

Given the following type hierarchy:

```
public class GenericBaseClass<T> { }

public class SpecializedClass<T, E extends Enum<E> & SomeInterface> extends GenericBaseClass<T> { }

public class SomeProvider {
    private static final List<SpecializedClass<Foo, ?>> VALUES =
        Arrays.asList(createValue());

    List<SpecializedClass<Foo, ?>> getValues() {        
        return VALUES;
    }

    private static SpecializedClass<Foo, Bar> createValue() {
        return new SpecializedClass<>();
    }
}

public class Foo {}
public enum Bar implements SomeInterface {}
public interface SomeInterface {}
```

The `SomeProvider` is supposed to expose a List of available `SpecializedClass` for the concrete type `Foo`. (To simplify the example here is only one concretion given for the type `Bar`.)

According to https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1452

> Generic wildcard types should not be used in return parameters

this snippet is marked as critical code smell by sonar.

Soo far I was not able to get rid of the wildcard here. Changing the getter method to

```
List<GenericBaseClass<Foo>> getValues() {        
    return VALUES;
}
```

will avoid the warning, but the client loses the information, that this list only contains instances of `SpecializedClass`.

Basically I have two questions here:

1. Is this really such a bad code smell in this case? What might be the pitfalls for the client using this getter method here?
2. How should the getter look like without using a wildcard in the return type?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Well, assuming that there can be quite a bunch of `SpecializedClass<Foo, ?>` variants in that list there's no other way to tell the compiler what to expect here. However, the question would be whether the information that the list only contains `SpecializedClass` instances is really that important. Generally such a design might become necessary at some point but the code smell is there for a reason: this might hint at some flaws with your general design.

Comment: Notice that the "Noncompliant Code Example" features a *bounded* wildcard. Bounded wildcards are annoying because they're so verbose; but if you genuinely need to return something for which you're essentially saying "no type information here!", that seems fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong using

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class SomeProvider {

  private static final List<SpecializedClass<Foo, Bar>> VALUES =
      Collections.singletonList(createValue());

  List<SpecializedClass<Foo, Bar>> getValues () {
    return VALUES;
  }

  private static SpecializedClass<Foo, Bar> createValue () {
    return new SpecializedClass<>();
  }
}
```

?

Edit:

Also possible but unsure about your static code analysis is

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class SomeProvider {

  private static final List<SpecializedClass<Foo, ? extends SomeInterface>> VALUES =
      Arrays.asList(createValue1(), createValue2());

  List<SpecializedClass<Foo, ? extends SomeInterface>> getValues () {
    return VALUES;
  }

  private static SpecializedClass<Foo, Bar1> createValue1 () {
    return new SpecializedClass<>();
  }

  private static SpecializedClass<Foo, Bar2> createValue2 () {
    return new SpecializedClass<>();
  }
}
```

which at least binds your return type to a subtype of `SomeInterface`.

Comment: ty for your answer. As mentioned in the question `(To simplify the example here is only one concretion given for the type Bar.` the list may contain different instances of `SpecializedClass` .. e.g. some `SpecializedClass<Foo, Bar2>`

Comment: I see - in this case I refer to Thomas comment.